# How to render page 404 on dynamic routes : React

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to redirect the user if he types a wrong id in the route below, to the Page404.
I tried to create a new route with path="/location/*" but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
          <Route path="/location/:id" element={<LocationPage/>} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Page404/>} />
```

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import locations from "../data/data.json";
import { Carousel, Infos } from "../components/LocationPageComponents"
import { Accordeon } from '../components';

const LocationPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const location = locations.find(location => location.id === id)
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Carousel pictures={location.pictures} key={"Carousel"}/>
        <Infos currentLocation={location}/>
        <div className="more-infos">
          <Accordeon content={{title: "Description", reply: location.description }} />
          <Accordeon content={{title: "Équipements", equipments: location.equipments }} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
}

export default LocationPage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when you type an `id`  that doesn't exist to your location path, the fallback path won't be triggered because the routing is correct. The url is matched and it will show the `LocationPage` component.

What you can do it is show an empty location component when no `location` is found.
Or use an effect to route to a different page, but this might not be what you want.

```js
const LocationPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const location = locations.find(location => location.id === id);

  if (!location) {
    return <EmptyLocationPage />
  }


  // ...
}
```

Your fallback route will only be triggered by routes that are not defined in your routes component. Like these for example:

```js
/location/1/fail
/locations
/location
/whatever
```

Comment: I didn't thought about doing something that easy. It works perfectly ! Thanks